# Minimax method in an AI TicTacToe game

Tags: python, function, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

The following code describes an AI TicTacToe game(the main file is game.py)

```
**player.py:**

import math
import random


class Player():
    def __init__(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter

    def get_move(self, game):
        pass


class HumanPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):
        valid_square = False
        val = None
        while not valid_square:
            square = input(self.letter + '\'s turn. Input move (0-9): ')
            try:
                val = int(square)
                if val not in game.available_moves():
                    raise ValueError
                valid_square = True
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid square. Try again.')
        return val


class RandomComputerPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):
        square = random.choice(game.available_moves())
        return square


class SmartComputerPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):
        if len(game.available_moves()) == 9:
            square = random.choice(game.available_moves())
        else:
            square = self.minimax(game, self.letter)['position']
        return square

    def minimax(self, state, player):
        max_player = self.letter  # yourself
        other_player = 'O' if player == 'X' else 'X'

        # first we want to check if the previous move is a winner
        if state.current_winner == other_player:
            return {'position': None, 'score': 1 * (state.num_empty_squares() + 1) if other_player ==       max_player else -1 * (
                        state.num_empty_squares() + 1)}
        elif not state.empty_squares():
            return {'position': None, 'score': 0}

        if player == max_player:
            best = {'position': None, 'score': -math.inf}  # each score should maximize
        else:
            best = {'position': None, 'score': math.inf}  # each score should minimize
        for possible_move in state.available_moves():
            state.make_move(possible_move, player)
            sim_score = self.minimax(state, other_player)  # simulate a game after making that move

            # undo move
            state.board[possible_move] = ' '
            state.current_winner = None
            sim_score['position'] = possible_move  # this represents the move optimal next move

            if player == max_player:  # X is max player
                if sim_score['score'] > best['score']:
                    best = sim_score
            else:
                if sim_score['score'] < best['score']:
                    best = sim_score
        return best

**game.py:**

import math
import time
from player import HumanPlayer, RandomComputerPlayer, SmartComputerPlayer


class TicTacToe():
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = self.make_board()
        self.current_winner = None

    @staticmethod
    def make_board():
        return [' ' for _ in range(9)]

    def print_board(self):
        for row in [self.board[i*3:(i+1) * 3] for i in range(3)]:
            print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

    @staticmethod
    def print_board_nums():
        # 0 | 1 | 2
        number_board = [[str(i) for i in range(j*3, (j+1)*3)] for j in range(3)]
        for row in number_board:
            print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

    def make_move(self, square, letter):
        if self.board[square] == ' ':
            self.board[square] = letter
            if self.winner(square, letter):
                self.current_winner = letter
            return True
        return False

    def winner(self, square, letter):
        # check the row
        row_ind = math.floor(square / 3)
        row = self.board[row_ind*3:(row_ind+1)*3]
        # print('row', row)
        if all([s == letter for s in row]):
            return True
        col_ind = square % 3
        column = [self.board[col_ind+i*3] for i in range(3)]
        # print('col', column)
        if all([s == letter for s in column]):
            return True
        if square % 2 == 0:
            diagonal1 = [self.board[i] for i in [0, 4, 8]]
            # print('diag1', diagonal1)
            if all([s == letter for s in diagonal1]):
                return True
            diagonal2 = [self.board[i] for i in [2, 4, 6]]
            # print('diag2', diagonal2)
            if all([s == letter for s in diagonal2]):
                return True
        return False

    def empty_squares(self):
        return ' ' in self.board

    def num_empty_squares(self):
        return self.board.count(' ')

    def available_moves(self):
        return [i for i, x in enumerate(self.board) if x == " "]


def play(game, x_player, o_player, print_game=True):

    if print_game:
        game.print_board_nums()

    letter = 'X'
    while game.empty_squares():
        if letter == 'O':
            square = o_player.get_move(game)
        else:
            square = x_player.get_move(game)
        if game.make_move(square, letter):

            if print_game:
                print(letter + ' makes a move to square {}'.format(square))
                game.print_board()
                print('')

            if game.current_winner:
                if print_game:
                    print(letter + ' wins!')
                return letter  # ends the loop and exits the game
            letter = 'O' if letter == 'X' else 'X'  # switches player

        time.sleep(.8)

    if print_game:
        print('It\'s a tie!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_player = SmartComputerPlayer('X')
    o_player = HumanPlayer('O')
    t = TicTacToe()
    play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game=True)
```

As you can see, the programmer used an minimx algorithmus to minimize the possibility to lose and to maximize the possibility to win. Now after several days of trying to understand how this minimax method works, I can't help but ask you guys to explain this to me.

1.what is the reasoning behind adding this code to player.py and how does the method return a score that will be greater than the initial value of negative infinity?:

```
if player == max_player:
 best = {'position': None, 'score': -math.inf}
else:
 best = {'position': None, 'score': math.inf}
```

2.in our simscore variabel we added the otherplayer parameters into our minimax function. Why did we do that? And doesnt we need to add the variable max_player as a parameter to minimax() to simulate a game?

3. How does recursion in this specific case work?

Comment: check out the return when `if state.current_winner == other_player`

Answer (score 0):

> 1.what is the reasoning behind adding this code to player.py and how does the method return a score that will be greater than the initial
> value of negative infinity?:

```py
if state.current_winner == other_player:
    return {
        'position': None,
        'score': 1 * (state.num_empty_squares() + 1) if other_player == max_player else -1 * (state.num_empty_squares() + 1)}
```

or I think alternately:

```py
    if state.current_winner == other_player:
        position = None
        score = state.num_empty_squares() + 1
        if other_player == max_player:
            score = -score
        return {'position': None, 'score': score}
```

If the player that moved last at this move in the tree of all moves "won" then that is ultimately good for that player and bad for the other player. Wins with more empty spaces are better.

> 2.in our simscore variabel we added the otherplayer parameters into our minimax function. Why did we do that? And doesnt we need to add
> the variable max_player as a parameter to minimax() to simulate a
> game?

`minimax()` is called recursively simulating a game. When called it switches players via `other_player = 'O' if player == 'X' else 'X'` when we pass the "current" `other_player` into the next move, `minimax()` can determine who moves in this call.

> 3. How does recursion in this specific case work?

Each call of `minimax()` allows for a simulated move by one of the two players. inside this method, the current moving player is `other_player`. A move is selected based on the current game state and `minimax()` is called to simulate the next player moving.